# JavaScript RegExp: Can I get the last matched index or search backwards/RightToLeft?

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose I have a string

```
foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz
```

I want to find for the last occurance of bar, how can I effectively do this? do I need to loop through add matches? In .NET I can do a RightToLeft search in JS, I guess I can't?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
bar(?!.*bar)
```

will find the last `bar` in a string:

```
bar   # Match bar
(?!   # but only if it's not followed by...
 .*   # zero or more characters
 bar  # literal bar
)     # end of lookahead
```

If your string may contain newline characters, use

```
bar(?![\s\S]*bar)
```

instead. `[\s\S]` matches any character, including newlines.

For example:

```
match = subject.match(/bar(?![\s\S]*bar)/);
if (match != null) {
    // matched text: match[0]
    // match start: match.index
}
```

You might also want to surround your search words (if they are indeed words composed of alphanumeric characters) with `\b` anchors to avoid partial matches.

```
\bbar\b(?![\s\S]*\bbar\b)
```

matches the solitary `bar` instead of the `bar` within `foobar`:

```
Don't match bar, do match bar, but not foobar!
  no match---^     match---^    no match---^
```

Comment: The dots are problematic since they don't match newline characters.

Comment: @Mike Samuels: Good point; have included an alternative regex for this case.

Answer (score 2):

Use the built-in function `lastIndexOf`:

```
"foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz".lastIndexOf("bar");
```

If you want to find the last "word" "bar":

```
(" "+"foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz"+" ").lastIndexOf(" bar ");
```