# Javascript - RegExp - Replace last occurrence of non-number

Tags: javascript, regex

So this is my code:

```
function PlusMinus() {
  str = str.replace(/([^\d\.](?!.*[^\d\.]))/, function(m, $1) {
    if ($1 == "-") return "";
    return $1 + "-";
  });
}
```

And it isn't working.

What I want to do, is to find the **last** occurrence of any character that is **not** a number (0-9) or a dot (.) and then if it is a "-", remove it, if it isn't replace the char with the char + "-".

Simply like a calculators -/+ button.

Examples:

```
"" -> "-"
"-" -> ""
"abc2-3" -> "abc23"
"a2-" -> "a2"
"s23.3" -> "s-23.3"
"4f" -> "4f-"
```

And yes, I've seen this: [JavaScript RegExp: Can I get the last matched index or search backwards/RightToLeft?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313918/javascript-regexp-can-i-get-the-last-matched-index-or-search-backwards-righttol) but I can't get it to work for chars in **brackets**

Comment: Provide some examples.

Comment: I guess you know that `.replace()` returns the new string instead of modifying the input one? That is to say, you need a left var: `anyVar = str.replace(...);`.

Comment: @sp00m Ik, but that wasn't the problem, edited though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
plusMinus(''); //'-'
plusMinus('-'); //''
plusMinus('abc2-3'); //'abc23'
plusMinus('a2-'); //'a2'
plusMinus('s23.3'); //s-23.3

function plusMinus(str) {
    return str.replace(/(^|[^\d\.])(?=[\d\.]*$)/, function ($0) {
        return $0 === '-'? '' : $0 + '-';
    });
}
```

I am just unsure about what to do with something like `33`, because now it will return `-33`. Is this the desired behavior?

Comment: Yes it is, also, does $0 actually work??? Like, shouldn't the arguments be (match, $1, $2, $3...)

Comment: @Murplyx It's just the argument name. It could have been anything, but usually `$0` is considered as full match so I chose this argument name. You could change it to `match` if you like it better.

Comment: As well, is there anyway to make this work for "abc123Infinity" -> "abc123-Infinity"

Comment: Is this: /(^|[^\d\.]|^Infinity)(?=[\d\.]|(Infinity)*$)/ correct then?

Comment: @Murplyx Will Infinity always be at the end? What would be the rule?

Comment: "Infinity" -> "-Infinity", "Infinity2" -> "Infinity-2", "Infinityabc" -> "Infinityabc-"

Comment: Wait.. "4f" -> "-4f", should be "4f-"

Answer (score 1):

I would say something like this:

```
str.replace(/(?:^|.)(?=[\d.]*$)/,function(c) {
    return c == "-" ? "" : c+"-";
});
```

This will find a character such that all the characters after it are either numbers or a dot. Due to the greedy nature of quantifiers and the left-to-right processing of regexes, this will be the first such character found, which will be the last non-digit, non-dot character.

However, be sure to `return` or otherwise do something with the result! Otherwise you're just discarding it.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, because I initially thought it was the same as my idea, but there are issues with your regular expression.

Comment: Well,  with `(/.(?=[\d.]+)$/` it's not working at all since the `$` is outside the lookahead, but there are also other issues, since for exemple, in `333`, the first `3` would be matched by your `.`. You also do not consider the case where `''` must yield `'-'`.

Comment: @plalx Gotcha. Thanks, now fixed I believe.

Comment: Also, your code doesn't work?? Have you tried with the examples?

Comment: @Murplyx Ah, I see. I (wrongfully) assumed that there would actually be a number for your +/- to apply to. Edited. [See tests](http://jsfiddle.net/pdp6w30h/)

Comment: Wait.. "4f" -> "-4f", should be "4f-"

Comment: @Murplyx And so it is. I forgot to add that test, but you can add it yourself easily enough to see that it does become `4f-`