# get only the last match? .match(word)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a regex to get @user from a textarea. When user type something with @ I get it.

My problem is, I want to get just the last match, not all of them.

eg:

user type:

```
@josh and @marie = want to show @marie
@josh loves @marie and @anne = show @anne
```

my code is showing like this:

```
@josh,@marie,@anne
```

Can I get just the last @something entry? (while user is typing)

```
var word=/@(\w+)/ig;

$("#comment").on("keyup",function() {

    var content = $(this).val();
    var name = content.match(word);
    var dataString = name;

    if(name.length > 0) {
        $("#result").text(name);
    }
    return false();
});
```

html

```
<textarea id=comment>@josh and @marie</textarea>
<div id=result></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dcs5pat8/ (press on textarea)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript RegExp: Can I get the last matched index or search backwards/RightToLeft?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313918/javascript-regexp-can-i-get-the-last-matched-index-or-search-backwards-righttol)

Comment: look at this 

blog.bigbinary.com/2010/03/31/regular-expressions-in-JavaScript.html

match method

match method acts exactly like exec method if no g parameter is passed. When global flag is turned on the match returns an Array containing all the matches.

Comment: what about using substring?

Comment: @mfadel any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Note this: `return false()`.... `false` IS NOT A FUNCTION!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides getting all matches and obtain the last one, you can use capture groups to get the last match:

```
var word=/.*(@\w+)/i;
var name = content.match(word)[1];
```

Or using exec, the whole would look like:

```
var word=/.*(@\w+)/i;

$("#comment").on("input",function() { //changed keyup to input

var content=$(this).val();
var match = word.exec(content); 

if(match){
 $("#result").text(match[1]);
}

});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dcs5pat8/11/)

PS, if your goal is a more generic approach and you need to switch between getting all words and a single one, I'd recommend keeping the global match and getting the last as in Jonas' answer.

Comment: How can you see the result in the Fiddle ?

Comment: @MrRubix The fiddle uses the same approach as the original post and reacts on keyup events in the textbox. Even using directional keys while in the textbox should trigger the event ( @ OP , instead of keyup you could also use on `input` or on `change` )

Comment: I will try! is it hard to get the last match entered? for example user type `@a` `@c` and want to add `@b` in the middle of this so my array output would be `@a` `@c` `@b` because b was the last one he types.

Comment: So you're saying you don't want the last name in the text, but rather the last name entered? You can get all matches and compare their index to the current position inside the textbox, but then you would have to deal with typing after the user goes back to the end of the input. An array could be kept with previous values, but if the user types the same name again, that would be the last. Could I summarize by suggesting you want to get only the match if one was just typed in and otherwise ignore other matches?

Comment: @Me.Name yes, it is! it would be better for what I want, but your answer is also good.

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is that you show only the last entry of your results.

You can do that by changing the line:
`var name = content.match(word);`

to

```
var names = content.match(word);
var name = names[names.length - 1];
```

On more detail, what this does is it gets all the results from your regex, then it attributes the last item of the array to the `name` variable.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: `content.match(word)` already returns an array, there's no reason/need to split it.

Comment: You don't need to put the `split` function at the end of the match. I was going to edit it, but there is a pending edit. Please look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dcs5pat8/9/

Answer (score 2):

You can simply select or pop the last match in the array of match returned by .match()

```
var word=/@(\w+)/ig;

$("#comment").on("keyup",function() {

    var content=$(this).val();
    var matches = content.match(word);
    var lastmatch = matches.pop();

    //IF YOU NEED TO KEEP INTACT THE VAR MATCHES
    //var lastmatch = matches[matches.length - 1];


    if(name.length>0){
        $("#result").text(lastmatch);
    }
    return false();
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dcs5pat8/16/)

Answer (score 1):

**Use** this regex **'/@(\w+)$/ig'** insted of '/@(\w+)/ig'.

And then your code will run like a charm. ;)

```
var word=/@(\w+)$/ig;

$("#comment").on("keyup",function() {

var content=$(this).val();
var name = content.match(word);
var dataString = name;

if(name.length>0){
 $("#result").text(name);
}
return false();
});
```

See it hear https://jsfiddle.net/dcs5pat8/1/

Comment: This will actually not work if the `@word` is not the last word of the phrase, i.e. if you have `@john loves @marie potatoes` your regex will find nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I do like the answer where you take your list with all of the @names,@name1,@name2 and just split off the last one, but here it is in just one step

```
//split on @something
//the penultimate item is our target
//if there is < 2 items there weren't any @somethings so return ''
user = (split = "testing @charlie testing".split(/(@[^ ]*)/)).length > 1 ? split.splice(-2,1)[0] : '';
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ek19h0fb/1/

Answer (score 0):

To have only one line you can do

```
var name = content.match(word).reverse()[0];
```